# Match Regex if not inside specific HTML tag

Tags: javascript, html, regex

I would like to get special formatted strings (`{string}`) out of the HTML which are not inside a specific HTML tag.

For example I would like to match `{test}` and not `<var>{test}</var>`.

Therefore I am using the following regex: (excluding is done with `?!`)

```
(?!<var>)\{\S+?\}(?!<\/var>)
```

So this works very well for texts with spaces, but if I have something like (where there is no space in-between):

```
<var>{name}</var>{username}
```

it matches two `{}`-strings: `{name}</var>{username}`

How can I just match `{username}` here?

**Update:**
If I need to do something like this

```
<var.*?<\/var>|(\{\S+?\})
```

How can I get the matched values, because the matched index depends on the position.

**Examples:**

Match 1:

```
"{username}<var>{name}</var>".match(/<var.*?<\/var>|(\{\S+?\})/g);
=> ["{username}", "<var>{name}</var>"]
```

Match 2:

```
"<var>{name}</var>{username}".match(/<var.*?<\/var>|(\{\S+?\})/g);
=> ["<var>{name}</var>", "{username}"]
```

**Current Solution:**

```
angular.forEach(html.match(regex), function (match) {
  if(match.substring(0, 4) !== '<var') {
    newAdded = match;
  }
});
```

Is this really the 'best' solution for JavaScript?

Comment: I think this one is better: [*Match text not inside span tags*](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24356167/match-text-not-inside-span-tags).

Comment: yes this one is better then the duplicated question! One question to that answer: Do you know how I can use the matched value, because the position depends on where it is found, either: http://www.rubular.com/r/RKVJSGIsvQ or http://www.rubular.com/r/qK5wYnlJCR

Comment: You need to check if the captured group is `!== undefined` and add the corresponding logic.

Comment: Thank you for your answer, I updated my question, because in javascript I also get the matches with HTML tag in the result.

Comment: When 'RegEx match open tags except XHTML self-contained tags' is your first related question, you should worry: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1732348/regex-match-open-tags-except-xhtml-self-contained-tags?rq=1

Comment: just care about using regexp to parse HTML ;)
 http://stackoverflow.com/a/1732454/2835089

Comment: @arnaudbey yes but this is a special case, I know exactly how the tag and its content look like. So I think it is safe to use regex for that!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here is how you can achieve this using the following regex:

```
/<var.*?<\/var>|(\{\S+?\})/g;
```

```js
var s = '<var>{name}</var>{username}<var>{newname}</var>{another_username}';
var log = [];
var m;
var regex = /<var.*?<\/var>|(\{\S+?\})/g;
while ((m = regex.exec(s)) !== null) {
   if ( m[1] !== undefined) {
     log.push(m[1]);
   }
}
alert(log);
```

Comment: thank you :) I trimmed it a little bit: ``while ((m = regex.exec(s))) {
      if (m[1]) {
        log.push(m[1]);
      }
    }``